# AutoCompleteTextView input Text and digits

Tags: android, android-layout

we have a AS400 Solution on a MDE-Device.
The screen of this application is 24 x 23 signs.

The people works on the Application only with digits for states, sizes, damages, ...

The files are always digit and text.
In the new app they should have the possibility to work with numbers and text.

[image]

[image]

I defined a 8 `ImageButton` and 8 `AutoCompleteTextViews` for each state.
How I can handle it, when the Employee enter for example 96, that I switch to the next `AutoCompleteTExteViews` (if it is a singlematch).

Or how would you solve that?

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, I updated answer.
You may add TextWatcher and validate user input:

```
autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (isValid(s)) { // your method to validate user input
           setWholeTextString(); // get whole string from your adapter or items list
           jumpToNextView(); 
        }
    }
});
```